# JDBC & Hiberntate Error in DB2 : Connection authorization failure occurred | SQL Error: -99999, SQLState: 42505

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, db2

Hello guys i tried to UPDATE a row in a DB2 table but i get a error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Connection authorization failure occurred.
```

In hibernate I have this:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("UPDATE Scsret set pollife = 'x' ");
    sb.append("WHERE id = 68197");// test dummy update

    Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(sb.toString());

    int update = query.executeUpdate();
```

And get this error

```
WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: -99999, SQLState: 42505
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Connection authorization failure occurred.
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:413)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:282)
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection authorization failure occurred.
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:405)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnection.checkAccess(AS400JDBCConnection.java:388)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCStatement.commonPrepare(AS400JDBCStatement.java:1149)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.java:248)
```

And i tried also using Pure Jdbc, but i get the same

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("UPDATE LSMODDTA.SCSRET SET FEMI  = 20140102 WHERE ID = ");
    sb.append("68196"); //test dummy update

    try {
        PreparedStatement  preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sb.toString());

        int update = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        System.out.println(update);



        //System.out.println(update);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And produce this error

```
 java.sql.SQLException: Connection authorization failure occurred.
    at com.ibm.as400.access.JDError.throwSQLException(JDError.java:405)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnection.checkAccess(AS400JDBCConnection.java:388)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCStatement.commonPrepare(AS400JDBCStatement.java:1149)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.java:248)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(AS400JDBCConnection.java:2088)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(AS400JDBCConnection.java:1887)
```

In SQL editor run the query that generated Hibernate, and work perfect

```
update
        LSMODDTA.SCSRET 
set
        pollife='x' 
where
        id=68196
```

**Both connections have the same user**

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be caused when the established connection is set as "readOnly" (Read more at: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1016865).

You could solve this by explicitly setting to FALSE the readOnly flag of your connection:

```
connection.setReadOnly(false);
```